# What's the name for the different kind of "offroad" "paths"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm gonna try to explain what I mean with this topic. So I'm sorry my English.

I'm doing a list of keywords to classify a series of photo' Scouting Locations. So I'm doing it in Spanish (my mother language) and English.

So I need the name in English for these different kind of path on outdoor areas:

1) The one where I can just hike. Normally only a person could walk and not a 4x4 car (like jeep wrangler), just people. There is not space to drive with 4x4 etc. If you want to get the top of a mountain, the whole way goes through this kind of paths. What's the name for this kind of route?

2) The ones where you can drive with cars like 4x4 because there is space enough (and it's allowed by laws). You can also hike. Looks like normal roads but without paviment. Some of them goes through forests, some not.  What's the name for this one?

3) The ones we call in Spanish "cortafuego" and I'm not sure if in English, Firewall is used for the same thing. A "cortafuego" is similar to the second case I asked but this ones connect ( at least here where I live) two of the one that right now don't kow the name (the second case). They are made to avoid the fire across this line if it gets this line. I know Firewall is something that computers use to block some specifics external and internal tasks BUT I'm not sure if for this case, is the same word.

By now that's all guys. I hope my doubt explanation has sense (or a bit of it)

Thanks and regards.
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) [**A walking trail**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trail) or *a hiking trail*.

2) The closest thing that I can think of would be [**dirt road**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirt_road).

3) I think in English you would call that [**a firebreak**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebreak).

The words listed above are by far probably the most common ones. Though, there are a million other terms to describe different variations of those types of roads. For further information, take a closer look at the Wikipedia pages I attached to this post.

Answer (score 0):

In [UK legal terms for Rights of Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rights_of_way_in_England_and_Wales) they would be;

1. Footpath / public footpath, or *bridleway* (horses allowed)
2. This is called a "[Green lane](https://www.glass-uk.org/)" in the 4x4 / motorbike world, technically it's classified as a road and officially a *byway open to all traffic* (or BOAT)
3. I'm not certain on this one, a fire-break gap (vegetation removed but not specifically prepared for walking or driving on) or possibly fire trail / fire road.

Per the wikipedia page I linked, there are other categories such as "Road Used As Public Path" but these may or may not be useful distinctions to most people who just want to go walking.